# Syntax Error in Window service

Tags: window

I am replacing Registry values in app config file and reading values from app.config. Could you please confirm if the below statment will bahave the same way as this statement does.

```
    string serversAndDatabases = regKey.GetValue("ServersAndDatabases","").ToString();
```

My updated code:

```
    string serversAndDatabases =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServersAndDatabases"].ToString();
```

Thanks & Regards,
Care Career

Answer (score 0):

It should not have an impact until we are getting the values, the same as with the registry.

It is ok to use a properties file instead of the Windows Registry. In this way we can get the benefit of "Platform Independent".

Be aware that the Registry can have values in different data types like String, DWORD etc....